# how to remove every white space and line break before string in react native?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to remove every white space and line break before the first character.

For example,

```
let str = " \n \n hello, my name is jay"

// do something

str = "hello, my name is jay"
```

No matter how many line breaks and white spaces are in front of the first character, I want to remove all of them.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You could just try this:

```
str = str.replace("\n", "").trim()
```

That'll replace all the `\n` and trim spaces off your string.

Comment: While this might achieve what the OP wants, note that this is not a direct answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The following find and replace seems to be working:

```
Find:    let\s+(\S+)\s*=\s*"(?:\s|\\[nrt])+(.*?)"
Replace: let $1 = "$2"
```

### Demo

The strategy is to match and capture the string literal definition, while removing the leading whitespace, should it be present.  This answer assumes that you want to apply a regex to actual source code script to remove leading whitespace from string literal definitions.